# How to write Terms Lookup query in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to execute the below query from NEST. I have taken this example from 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html

> ## search on all the tweets that match the followers of user 2

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tweets/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : {
            "index" : "users",
            "type" : "user",
            "id" : "2",
            "path" : "followers"
          },
          "_cache_key" : "user_2_friends"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```